# Sub-shell process not be able to access variables and functions defined in parent shell

Tags: bash, function, shell, variables, subshell

I have 3 scripts in the same directory, please find below contents of x.sh, y.sh and z.sh :-

x.sh :-

```
xData="DataOfX"

function xInit(){
    echo "xInit : data of a >$xData<"
}
```

y.sh :-

```
. x.sh

xInit

sh z.sh zInit
```

z.sh :-

```
function zInit(){
    echo "zInit of z"
    xInit
}

$@
```

Executing

> . y.sh

in the same directory gives below output :-

```
xInit : data of a >DataOfX<
zInit of z
z.sh: line 3: xInit: command not found
```

How can a sub-shell process can access the variables and functions initialised in the parent shell?

Comment: Use export for exporting the variables.

Answer (score 6):

The term "sub-shell" is problematic, and even `man bash` is inconsistent in the way it is used.  Strictly speaking a sub-shell is another shell environment which inherits all features, including all variables, of the parent.

Parentheses gives a subshell.  The variable `BASH_SUBSHELL` gives the *level* of subshell, and `$$` gives the `PID` of the shell (in subshells it is faked to be the PID of the parent).

```
$ x=42

$ echo $BASH_SUBSHELL, $x, $$
0, 42, 1130
$ (echo $BASH_SUBSHELL, $x, $$)
1, 42, 1130
$ ( (echo $BASH_SUBSHELL, $x, $$) )
2, 42, 1130
```

When you execute a script, *that is not a subshell*.  Take a script `gash.sh` with:

```
echo $BASH_SUBSHELL, $x, $$
```

Running it as:

```
$ ./gash.sh
0, , 8419
```

Notice the blank because `x` is not copied.  It is not a subshell, and the PID is different.  Even

```
$ (./gash.sh)
1, , 8421
```

that is a subshell running a child process, so that doesn't work either.

You need to move the variable to the *environment block*, which is copied to child processes, using `export`:

```
$ export x
$ ./gash.sh
0, 42, 8423
```

Variables that are not exported are only available in subshells using `( )`, not other child processes.  For functions use `export -f`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `export` should do the work:

```
export xData="DataOfX"
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/export.htm

> export- command is one of the bash shell BUILTINS commands, which
>   means it is part of your shell. The export command is fairly simple to
>   use as it has straightforward syntax with only three available command
>   options. In general, the export command marks an environment variable
>   to be exported with any newly forked child processes and thus it
>   allows a child process to inherit all marked variables.